# Get inward and outward codes from UK postal code

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm trying to find a way to split a UK postcode from the user entry. The initial entry is validated by the below regex and it's working fine.

```
var regex = @"^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([AZa-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$";
```

Now I need to split the postcode into outward and inward codes so that I can send them separately to the client's ERP to get the shipping cost.

Example.

> User input: **DD81UN**
>   Desired output: **DD8 1UN**
>
> User input: **DN551PT**
>   Desired output: **DN55 1PT**

Comment: What's the logic to separate outward and inward codes?

Comment: http://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/postcodeformat.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Only adding spaces:**

As per the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom) on outward and inward codes for UK Postal codes, the rules are as follows:

- An outward code is between two and four characters long
- An inward code is three characters long

So if you have already extracted the code, to add spaces or split, simply add a space before the 3rd character from the end since the inward code is *always 3 characters in length*:

```
string extractedCode = "DD81UN";
extractedCode = extractedCode.Insert(extractedCode.Length - 3, " ");
// Output: DD8 1UN
```

**Improving the Regular expression:**

Based on the rules in the [link](http://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/postcodeformat.pdf) you shared, here's a better version of the regex, that extracts UK Postal Codes from any text, even if they contain a space:

```
\b([A-PR-UWYZ](?:(?:\d{1,2}|\d[A-HJ-KSTUW])|(?:[A-HK-Y]\d(?:\d|[A-Z])?)))\s?(\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})\b
```

- `\b` represents word boundary at start and end
- `([A-PR-UWYZ](?:(?:\d{1,2}|\d[A-HJ-KSTUW])|(?:[A-HK-Y]\d(?:\d|[A-Z])?)))` is the first capturing group to match **outward code** which may be two to four characters in length.

  - `[A-PR-UWYZ]` since the first character cannot have `Q`, `V` or `X`
  - `(?:\d{1,2}|\d[A-HJ-KSTUW])` allows formats `AN`, `ANN` and `ANA` and restricts characters as per the rules in the third position
  - `(?:[A-HK-Y]\d(?:\d|[A-Z])?))` allows formats `AAN`, `AANN` and `AANA` and doesn't allow `I`, `J` and `Z` in the 2nd position
- `\s?` matches an optional space between outward and inward codes.
- `(\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})` is the second capturing group for outward codes. It allows one digit followed by two characters as per the rules.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xdwrG2/1/)

- The letters Q, V and X are not used in the first position
- The letters I,J and Z are not used in the second position.
- The only letters to appear in the third position are A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, J, K, S, T, U and W.
- The second half of the postcode is always consistent numeric, alpha, alpha format and the letters C, I, K, M, O and
  V are never used.

If your objective is to only match and add space, match using above and replace with `$1 $2` since the above regex matches outward codes in the first group and inward codes in the 2nd group.

Here's a [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oSBaVK) which demonstrates the same.

```
string input = "sample DD81UN DN55 1PT WRONG text 123456";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b([A-PR-UWYZ](?:(?:\d{1,2}|\d[A-HJ-KSTUW])|(?:[A-HK-Y]\d(?:\d|[A-Z])?)))\s?(\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})\b");

// To add spaces between each codes
string output = r.Replace(input, "$1 $2");

// To get all codes
var results = r.Matches(output);
```

Comment: Great. I was not sure about the length of the inward code. This works perfectly now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @samithagun added a dotnet fiddle demo as well as some explanation for the regex. If the answer helped solve your problem, you might want to mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
namespace UKPostCodeConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstPostCode = "DD81UN";
            string secondPostCode = "DN551PT";
            Console.WriteLine(ParseToUkPostcode(firstPostCode));
            Console.WriteLine(ParseToUkPostcode(secondPostCode));
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static string ParseToUkPostcode(string aPostcode)
        {
            string finalPostcode = aPostcode;

            finalPostcode = finalPostcode.Replace(" ", "").Trim();
            string outWardResult = finalPostcode.Substring(0, finalPostcode.Length - 3);
            string inWardResult = finalPostcode.Substring(Math.Max(0, finalPostcode.Length - 3));
            string postCodeResult = string.Format("{0} {1}", outWardResult, inWardResult);
            finalPostcode = postCodeResult;

            return finalPostcode;
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Hope it solves your problem